# having issue with multicloud

Tags: amazon-s3, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-shell

I am trying to run a sample multicloud project, but I got stuck in the middle. I will like to erase all what I have done from the AWS (License key) to the google shell (project) and some unzip file. so that I can start afresh.

I want start the project from the beginning, I don't want all the files I uploaded on it to be there.

Answer (score 0):

To reset Cloud Shell and restore your Cloud Shell home directory to a clean state, follow these steps:

1. `sudo rm -rf $HOME`
2. In the Cloud Shell menu, click More and then click Restart. If prompted, click Restart in the confirmation dialog.

This provisions a new VM and restores the home directory to its default state.

For more information, refer to this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/shell/docs/resetting-cloud-shell).